# The given path's format is not supported

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ftp, file-transfer

I try to move files with code below from `ftp://a.domain.con` to `ftp://b.domain.con`

```
 Public Function TransferFile(ByVal originalFile As String, ByVal destinationFile As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String) As String
        Try
            Dim fStream As New FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create)
            Dim fileRequest As FileWebRequest = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(originalFile)), FileWebRequest)
            fileRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
            fileRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userName, password)
            Dim response As WebResponse = fileRequest.GetResponse()
            Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
            Dim size As Long = 0
            Dim totalRead As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            While totalRead > 0
                size += totalRead
                fStream.Write(buffer, 0, totalRead)
                totalRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
            End While
            fStream.Close()
            stream.Close()
            Return "File transfered"
        Catch ex As SecurityException
            Return ex.Message
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

The problem is that on the first line

```
Dim fStream As New FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create)
```

i get `The given path's format is not supported.` error.

The Original filename is ftp://a.domain.con/102425547_��������_14.2.2011_1.zip
and the Destination one is ftp://b.domain.con/102425547_��������_14.2.2011_1.zip

By the way here comes the StackTrace...

```
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
```

and the �������� characters are Greek ones!

Comment: I am wondering why you decided that FileStream works with FTP URLs (or with URLs in general).

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski I'm a newbie!

Comment: Why are you reading 1024 bytes into 1023-byte buffer?

Comment: this doesn't justify not reading the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `FileStream` with FTP.

Instead, you need to create two `FtpWebRequest`s (one to read and one to write).

Comment: +1 - the winscp api also has some tools that can help do similar types of file processes including folder sync from server to folder which might be useful.

Comment: After some extra Googling, i found that i could use the FTPWebRequest.RenameTo Property to move the file into a new location. But i think that i cannot use that since the ftp credentials are not the same. Is that true?